# Keep "Live" app as well as "Dev" app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to keep the "live in the app store" version of an app on your phone, as well as the "beta" version I am currently working on adding features to?

I use my own app on a daily basis and v2.0 is still to buggy to use as the primary use app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the bundle identifier of the application in order to achieve this.

**Instructions**

1. Right click on your target in Xcode -> click 'Get Info'
2. Select the 'Properties' tab
3. Change the 'Identifier' field to something different. As of Xcode 3, this is the second field (right under 'Executable')

*NOTE*: You will need this to be the same in order for your application to be accepted upon submission to the App Store for updates. Remember to change this value back to the original before resubmitting.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to actually go to the .plist to get the changes to save.  The identifier field wouldn't update the plist  (Xcode 4)

Answer (score 1):

Imho a better way would be to create a second target. The time will come when you forget to switch the identifiers manually and then you have overwritten your app, and probably upgraded all the data which can't be undone. BTDTNT

1. In Xcode3 you would right click the existing target and select `duplicate`.
2. Rename the target to whatever you want.
3. Then you should rename the second plist, because the name `Project-Info copy.plist` isn't that nice.
4. Once you renamed the plist open the beta target info and put the new name into `Info.plist File`.